# Sometimes onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched() returns empty AppLinkData

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, deep-linking, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to get Deferred Deep Link after app install from Facebook Ads. Sometimes I get `empty AppLinkData`.
Deep link is setup correctly in Manifest and some `AppLinkData` returned in `onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched()` contains URI, but not regularly.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.splashScreenTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)

    AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(
        this
    ) {
        var deepLinkPath = ""
        val parameters = Bundle()
        it?.let {
            parameters.putString(
                getString(R.string.facebook_applinkdata_uri),
                it.targetUri.toString()
            )
            deepLinkPath = "&attr3=" + it.targetUri.path
        }
        firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("DeepLinkUriEvent", parameters)
    }
}
```